# convert and upload by click

Tags: php, canvas, upload

there is a canvas with picture on it and a button.
 user clicks on a button and it gets converted to img and that image sent to `form` and upload to server by PHP, i've tried to write something, but this one is out of my abilities.

how to do it? is there more easy way to solve the problem?

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="400px">HERE USER DRAW< /canvas>
<button onclick="to_image()">Draw to Image< /button>
```

here is to_image():

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
document.getElementById("theimage").src = canvas.toDataURL();
var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

i've tried to change button like this:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="to_image()">Save< /button>
```

and created hidden input, to put that image there:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```

finally change to_image() like:

```
document.getElementById("file").src = data;
```

still nothing happens, i'm new to javascript and php, so was a bit embarrassed to show code

Comment: -1: No code examples and no demonstration of effort.

Comment: ok, thank you, i'll add my code, but it's funny

Comment: Will remove the -1 when code is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to get the canvas data and turn it into a URL ([more information about toDataURL](http://khlo.co.uk/index.php/681-Canvas-Todataurl)):

```
var drawing = document.getElementById('canvas-id').toDataURL('image/png');
```

You could then feed this URL to the server via an AJAX call, and have it process from there. This will be base64 encoded so you'll have to do `base64_decode` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)), then you'll be left with an image blob which you can save with your PHP.

You'll have to use POST to submit the data as GET has length limits in IE and Chrome. I found an example of someone doing [something very similar here with full code examples](http://permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/), in case you get stuck with it.

Comment: so, you offer to send URL with POST to php and then use base64_decode and finally save it there?

Comment: You send the base64 encoded image blob with POST (via AJAX), yes, then `base64_decode` and save it.

Comment: [This example](http://permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/) should help you if you get stuck.

Comment: 'and save it' - how i should do it? i know copy() function, but didnt see save(), so what is the method for it?

Comment: Check out the example I added to my answer, basically does everything you want from getting canvas data to submitting it to saving it.